# How to run a remote jar from local Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, deployment, execute

Here's my situation (standalone jar program)

1. build jar
2. deploy jar to remote target - then to start debugging
3. execute jar (on target)
4. debug from my eclipse env. (I referred to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html)

I wonder there is any method to control step 3 on my eclipse. Without connecting target console and starting jar file, I would like to do all steps on Eclipse.

I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: you can implement a script which would do "connecting target console and starting jar file", but you would run that script from eclipse with double-click etc.

Comment: could you show any clue about script? should it be Ant?

Comment: well, can you show detailed trace from console in step 3?

Comment: java -cp ncfs.jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address="8000" ncs.ncfs.NCFSMain -p 15021 -r d:/data -d

Comment: It is not complete, before you can type that you need to start console, connect to remote server, type password and only then executing the command mentioned above. All these steps can be automated with smth like `bat`, `ttl`, `ssh`

Comment: Understood, it's not about java execution, but shell emulation using bat,ttl,ssh. I'll try it, Thank you.

Comment: Same can be done with Java, but probably shell emulation is easier approach.